# Where should callback function go if both base and derived class need to use the same function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, callback

Let's say I have a class Child that inherits from class Parent. Both classes need to be able to be able to send a function pointer of the same method, let's call it foo(), to an API.

I don't think I can make foo() a member function, since the process invoking the callback would need to have an object of either Child or Parent to call it with. I also don't think I can make foo() a static member function since there may be multiple instances of Parent of Child.

What would be the cleanest place to put foo() in this case? Should it go into its own file and have its own namespace, and get #include'd into both Parent and Child? Should foo() be in Parent only meaning Child would need to include Parent.cpp and forward declare foo()?

Appreciate any insight!

Comment: What's the matter with having multiple instances of Parent and Child and why does it prevent to use a static member function?

Comment: What's wrong with a static member? Are you saying the callback needs to be called with varying parameters? What is the API? Is the API in C? More details would be really helpful.

Comment: Brian, the API is in C. The API does not need to be called with varying parameters; but if I make foo() a static member function, and I have multiple Child objects all registering for the callback, how would each Child receive its corresponding callback?

Answer (score 1):

If your API need a pointer to a function, you can only give it either a static function or a plain function defined outside of any class. If you later need that this function calls a method on  one of your objects, you **need** that the API allows you to pass *something* (usualy a `void *`). If you can pass the API the function pointer **and** a `void *` you have won: just pass it a pointer to an object of class Parent or Child along with the pointer to a relay function.

Say the API will call a `int (*callback)(void *param /* other params...*/)`

You define something like:

```
int myCallback(void* param /* other params...*/) {
    Parent *parent = static_cast<Parent *>(param);
    return parent->myMethod(/* other params...*/);
}
```

That way:

- the API only knows a plain pointer to function and an opaque `void *`
- you can declare normal (or even virtual methods) in your classes
- the *relay* function is called by the API and in turns calls the methods on your objects

Answer (score 0):

I can understand why Foo() can't be a static function. It might be that the various Child and Parent objects want to have different Foo() functions.

Consider using an interface. Don't send a pointer to a method, but a reference to the interface which has the Foo() method.

I haven't programmed C++ for a few years now, so my C++ is a bit rusty, forgive me if it is C#. I guess you'll understand the Idea.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void Foo();
}

public class Parent : IMyInterface
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}

public class Child : Parent, IMyInterface
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
        DoSomethingElse()
        // if needed call Base.Foo();
    }
 }
```

Usage: Suppose you have an object that needs to call the Foo of an object. Alas it doesn't know whether the object is a Parent or a Child. Luckily it does not have to know what it is, it only has to know it has a function Foo. And that is done by promising that the object will implement IMyInterface

```
public class FooCaller
{
    private void CallFoo(IMyinterFace fooToBeCalled)
    {
        fooToBeCalled.Foo();
    }
}
```

So FooCaller doesn't know whether fooToBeCalled is a Parent or a Child. It only knows that if has a function Foo().

The nice thing about using an interface is that it can also be used if there is no relation between the objects

```
class Uncle : IMyInterface
{
    public void Foo() {...}
}
```

The Uncle is neither a Parent nor a Child, yet it can still be used by the FooCaller.

Using interfaces instead of base classes gives you the opportunity to focus on the minimal set of functions needed to perform a task. Thus making reuse of code more likely.

Comment: I think it is reasonable to assume that the OP can't change the API. So if the API needs a pointer to a function, then using interfaces won't really help.

Comment: Rozina, you are correct: I cannot change the API. Still, I appreciate the information Harald.